# Why i am getting this error in Command Line every time i create a react app and run with "npm start"?

Tags: reactjs, react-scripts

From some time i am always getting an error in Command Line related to my react-scripts when i run my react app using the command "npm start".I tried many solutions but nothing seem to work(like deleting node_module and reinstalling and also changing my "react-scripts" version in package.json file.The error is:

```
   E:\MYPROJECT\react-chat-app>npm start

   > react-app@0.1.0 start E:\MYPROJECT\react-chat-app
   > react-scripts start

   internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:638
   throw err;
   ^

   Error: Cannot find module './util/escape'
   at Function.Module._resolveFilename 
   (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:690:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\MYPROJECT\react-chat-app\node_modules\cross-
    spawn\lib\parse.js:6:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:776:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js 
    (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
     at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
     npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
     npm ERR! errno 1
     npm ERR! react-app@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
     npm ERR! Exit status 1
     npm ERR!
     npm ERR! Failed at the react-app@0.1.0 start script.
     npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely 
     additional logging output above.

     npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
     npm ERR!     C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-07-
     07T13_59_34_897Z-debug.log
```

And here is my package.json file

```
   {
   "name": "react-app",
   "version": "0.1.0",
   "private": true,
   "dependencies": {
   "@pusher/chatkit": "^0.7.12",
   "bootstrap": "^4.1.1",
   "chatkit": "0.0.1-security",
   "react": "^16.7.0",
   "react-dom": "^16.7.0",
   "react-scripts": "^3.0.1"
   },
   "scripts": {
   "start": "react-scripts start",
   "build": "react-scripts build",
   "test": "react-scripts test",
   "eject": "react-scripts eject"
   },
   "eslintConfig": {
   "extends": "react-app"
   },
   "browserslist": [
   ">0.2%",
  "not dead",
  "not ie <= 11",
  "not op_mini all"
  ]
  }
```

Before this i wasn't having any such errors and my app used to run without such problems.But now even my already created app show this error when i run it.

Comment: Are you importing `./util/escape` somewhere in your codebase?

Comment: not that i am aware of.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see in your `package.json` module `util`. Try install it `npm i util`

Comment: We usually do not have to install `util` our self. If your code runs in Node.js, util is built in.

Comment: i checked the documentation,it says util is preinstalled.And i have never installed it separately before and my app used to run.i dont know why i need it now.

Comment: @Pawan Did you try install?

Comment: yes i installed.but its still showing the same error